# How Can I Fetch WSDL APIs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am trying to fetch one of the links below. I got the message from the council that says **Failed to Fetch**. So, could you please guide me on how I can fetch the link?

APIs Links:

https://www.tcitips.com/api/TCi_PlaceOrder.cfc?wsdl

https://www.tcitips.com/api/TCi_PlaceOrder.wsdl

This is my work

```
fetch ('https://www.tcitips.com/api/TCi_searchSizeTIPS/wsdl')
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return result.json();
}).then(data =>{
    console.log(data); 
}).catch (error => console.log (error));
```

Comment: You need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on the backend server.

Comment: I have tried to use CORS but no result. I believe there is a mistake on the link I use to fetch.